# Why does the Contains(value) equal false when it contains the value?

Tags: c#

Here is the data, a Char-Array (board) and a list of Char-Arrays that are made up different three character sequences from board.

```
public static char[] board = { 'Q', '-', '+',
                               'A', '-', 'D',
                               '+', 'X', 'C' };

static List<char[]> dalist = new List<char[]> { 
        new char[3] { board[3], board[4], board[5] },
        new char[3] { board[0], board[4], board[8] },
        new char[3] { board[2], board[4], board[6] },
        new char[3] { board[1], board[4], board[7] },

        new char[3] { board[0], board[1], board[2] },
        new char[3] { board[6], board[7], board[8] },
        new char[3] { board[0], board[3], board[6] },
        new char[3] { board[2], board[5], board[8] }
};

static void Main(){   

    foreach (var item in dalist[2])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    // This returns + - + as expected


    Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].ToString().Contains("-"));
    // This returns false

}
```

Why does the .Contains method unexpectedly return false?

Comment: Have you check your : Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].ToString()); ? It contains only "System.char[]". Fix using : Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].Contains('-'));

Comment: Arrays are zero-based. perhaps you want index 1 not index 2. i.e. dalist[1]

Comment: It seems working [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/thhGTa)

Comment: Calling ToString on a char array in .NET will always return "char[]". You can either use new string(datalist[2]).Contains("-") or datalist[2].Contains("-").

Answer (score 3):

`daList[2]` is a `char[]`.  When you call `ToString()` on an array, it does not concatenate all the elements of the array into a string, it returns the class name, which in this case is `System.Char[]`.  You can see this for yourself if you do `Console.WriteLine(daList[2].ToString())`.  Since the literal string `"System.Char[]"` does not contain a hyphen, `daList[2].ToString().Contains("-")` returns false.

If you want to create a string out of a character array, there is a string constructor for that.  I think this is what you really want:

```
Console.WriteLine(new String(dalist[2]).Contains("-"));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLpJLV

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if datalist2 `contains` the character `-` by using `Contains` method of `array`

```
Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].Contains('-'));
```

Comment: Sorry, was my fault, I misread the question. On re-reading I relized that the `-`-character is contained twice in `board`. Now I can´t retract the vote

Comment: @HimBromBeere OP is trying to find a character inside List of array so it doesn't matter a character is contained twice or thrice.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `dalist[2]` is an array so `.Contains` will perfectly return `ture` or `false` depending on existence

Comment: I ment the very first occurence of `-` in the `board`-array. Assuming it *had*  the character only at position 2 and not also at position 5 (which for any weird reason I did, pardon me please), `dalist[2]` does **not** contain the character. That was my mistake, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataList` is not an array of characters, but a list of arrays. So what you´re after is the second element within the third list, or element at [2][1]. So you need this:

```
Console.WriteLine(datalist[2][1].ToString().Contains("-"));
```

Which can further be simplified to

```
Console.WriteLine(datalist[2][1] == '-');
```

Another approach would be to check if the list contains the character:

```
Console.WriteLine(datalist[2].Contains('-'));
```

The reson why your approach doesn´t work is that when calling `ToString` on an array of characters it won´t simply combine your characters but create something similar to `System.Char[]` which is obviously not what you expected. The `ToString`-method isn´t smart enough to first check the elements within and use there string-representation. However it simply returns the type of it´s containing elements.

Answer (score 0):

`dalist[2]` is not a single value, it is `char` array when you call `ToString()` on a char array you will get "`System.Char[]`" not "+-+" as you are thinking..

```
Console.WriteLine(dalist[2][1].ToString().Contains("-"));
// This will returns true
```

If you are looking to check for an existence of an item in an array remove `ToString()` and look for that character.

```
Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].Contains('-'));
```

Comment: Why down vote here? please leave your comments answer can be improved.

Comment: Why do you want to check if '-' contains '-' ? It should check if "+-+" contains '-'

Comment: It seems to me that this code accomplishes something different than the OP wanted. I.E: It checks if a singular space in the grid is a character, whereas the OP wants to see if a gridline contains a character.

Comment: @Stanley that's hwo ideally it should be, but int this example I'm explaining why it is failing.

Comment: @Knells Read the title, OP is asking why  contains is failing?

Comment: Read again carefully "Why does the .Contains method unexpectedly return false?"

Comment: @Stanley I was explaining why his statement is failing in the first statement, also explained what can be done.

Comment: @HariPrasad i think downvoters just love to downvote anyway.

Comment: @Leopard seems people are in bad mood today.

Comment: Sorry, was my fault, I misread the question. On re-reading I relized that the `-`-character is contained twice in `board`. Now I can´t retract the vote

Answer (score 0):

This one check if "System.Char[]" contains "-" and result is FALSE

```
Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].ToString().Contains('-'));
```

This one check if ["+"]["-"]["+"] contains "-" and result is TRUE

```
Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].Contains('-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string dalist2 = dalist[2][0].ToString() + dalist[2][1].ToString() + dalist[2][2].ToString();

Console.WriteLine(dalist2.Contains("-"));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(dalist[2].Contains('-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Modidfy your code from `.ToString()` to `.ToList()`
ie Change the code as follows

```
bool isContains = dalist[2].ToList().Contains('-');
```